# Non-conservative system and velocity dependent potentials

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, potential, potential-energy

I'm studying Lagrangian mechanics, but I'm a little bit upset because when dealing with Lagrange's equations, we mostly consider conservative systems. If the system is non conservative they are very brief by saying that 'sometimes' there exist a velocity dependent potential $U(q,\dot{q},t)$ such that the generalized force $Q_j$ of the standard system can be written in terms of this potential.
$$Q_j =\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial \dot{q}_j}\right)-\frac{\partial U}{\partial q_j}$$
They give as example, charged particles in a static EM field.

1. But my question is, if we can find this velocity dependent potential for any generalized force?
2. If not, we can't use Lagrangian mechanics?

Comment: related: [Lagrangian Equations of Motion, Conservative Forces](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255903)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *No,* (generalized) velocity dependent potentials $U(q,\dot{q},t)$ do not exist for all (generalized) forces $Q_j$. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20929/2451) Phys.SE post.
2. Even if no variational formulation exists, one may still consider Lagrange equations, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/283238/2451) Phys.SE post.